# Process for creating/updating a CocoaPod

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to create a new CocoaPod for [MarkupKit](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit). I've created the Podspec and verified it locally with `lint`. I've also pushed the Podspec to MarkupKit's GitHub repo and verified that I can pull it in as a dependency for a sample project.

However, I'm unclear on what to do next. Based on the [documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/), it seems like I now need to push the Podspec to the main Spec Repo. However, the docs also mention "trunk". I assume these are the same thing, but I'm not 100% sure.

It seems like my next step would be to request access to trunk. Then, once I have access, I believe I need to run the following command:

```
pod trunk push MarkupKit.podspec
```

Is this correct?

If so, do I still need to keep a copy of the Podspec in the MarkupKit repo after it has been submitted to trunk? What is the typical workflow for updating a CocoaPod after the initial deployment to the Specs Repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, `pod trunk push` is how you upload a podspec.

You will want to keep a copy of the Podspec in the repo, because the main Spec Repo doesn't store podspecs in the format you sent them. Instead, it uses a JSON representation which is harder for a human to read. Keeping a copy of it will let you update it easily in the future, and also test modifications locally.

Comment: Thanks. One additional workflow question. It seems like there may be a bit of a "chicken and egg" situation in this process. I can't verify (i.e. "lint") my Podspec until the version tag is created, but I don't want to create the version tag until I've verified the Podspec. How do you typically work around that?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that the Specs Repo and trunk refer to the same thing? If they are not, what is the distinction?

Comment: I create the tag in my personal fork of the repository and lint with the `source` parameter pointing to that fork. Once it passes lint, I merge the changes into the main repo, create the tag there, and submit the podspec (which will lint again).

Comment: The Cocoapods main specs repo is [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs). And `pod trunk` can be used to submit your podspecs there. Cocoapods can also be used with private spec repos, and it's possible that the `pod trunk` family of commands lets you do stuff with that too; but I've only ever used the main repo.